How to limit the effect of Contactors noise on the electronic circuits?
I have designed an electronic circuit that is used to switch 8 relays in certain circumstances (like 8 times in a minute). Then these relays switch on and off the contactors connected to AC electric motors. The main power line is 24 volts and all the components including the Contactors coil, micro switches, and my electronic board are connected to this line.
In my board, the 24 V decrease to 9 V with the LM2596 switching regulator (this 9 V is used to drive relays) and then to 3.3 V by AMS1117 linear regulator to drive the microprocessor (ESP32) and LCD (TFT ili9341 driver).
everything works fine until I install the board. when it starts switching (in a random manner) the LCD turns white and the microprocessor stops working (you will need to restart the board). This malfunction happens in a random manner. Sometimes it happens at the first minute, sometimes after 15 minutes. However, it is most likely to happen when it switches a couple number of contactors at the same time. So I assumed that maybe my power would drop out and I used a big capacitor at the input and also high current sources. But apparently, nothing changed.
I assume maybe there is a noise from the contactor magnetic coil in the 24 line that affects my circuit? Is there any component I can use to avoid?
I even used a separate 24 V source with this circuit (only the grounds were connected to the main 24 V line) and the problem happened again (maybe it got less, but happened). I only have 2 inputs which are all connected to the optocouplers and the output of the optocoupler is connected to the processor.
I also tested two conditions: first, I only connected the contactors' electromagnetic coils to the GND and 24V input of the circuit. I will upload the video so that you san see what is happening. After switching happens, the LCD goes white and circuit malfunctions.
In the second case, I powered a Drill, I pluged it into another plug, however, when the drill starts working, the circuits malfunctions. The interesting fact is that as you can see in the video, as drill spins faster, more noise becomes apparent on the circuit and eventually the LCD becomes white. So maybe magnetic flux is the destructive element here i guess? I guess magnetic flux is also apparent on the contactors coil too. how can I reduce the effect?
Link to videos on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ISLQFcksrPK8zW7Tq0MGag217XgiiEyE?usp=sharing
Thank you for your help



U8 is missing its decoupling capacitor.

Same with U5. What does your layout look like? When the contactor(s) switch, what does Vcc look like on your oscilloscope? Your optocouplers are near useless since both sides share ground, save for 1k//100n.

You mentioned contactors & relays but these don't appear on any of the schematics posted.  What loads are the contactors driving?

@FabioBarone the contactors are not in the schematic, because that is the costumers circuit, all we know is that contactors switch AC electro motors.

@winny unfortunately I don't have access to an oscilloscope. However, i have added two video links in the main post. it seems that we have a magnetic flux problem.

Information on contactor location, wiring runs, type of cable (shielded, ...) are crucial parts of the problem description. || Is your equipment housed in a shielded housing (eg steel box, or ...) These should be in the question, not added as comments. || An adequate oscilloscope can be bought for around $US30 online. I bought a small hand portable one via Aliexpress and am happy with its performance.  I can provide a link if of interest. || You can make an oscilloscope using a PC audio input and free online software. BUT an oscilloscope is an almost essential tool and repays its cost rapidly.

You can’t troubleshoot electronics without one. Have you added the decoupling capacitors I asked about?

If the contactor coils are DC, check the manufacturer’s documentation to see if they have inbuilt snubbers. You could add a varistor across each contactor coil. Something like a 33V 14mm device. As mentioned by others, the wiring layout can be critical. Where you see wires, I see resistors,capacitors, inductors and transformers.
